# How to use .get() multiple times pythonically?

Tags: python, dictionary

What is the most **pythonic/efficient** way of using `<dict>.get('<key>')` **multiple times** to access **different levels** of a dict?

(the examples are deliberately short but imagine many more keys and a  much longer original dictionary)

an **Example**:

instead of this:

```
    complete_data = {'name': 'bob',
                     'age':'22',
                     'items': [{'subitem':1,'another subitem':2}, 123, 456]}

    required_data['name'] = complete_data['name']

    required_data['another subitem'] = complete_data['items'][0]['another subitem']
```

we could use something like this:

```
    complete_data = {'name': 'bob', 'age':'22', 'other stuff': 'some stuff'}

    desired_keys = ['name','age']

    for i in range(len(desired_keys)):
        required_data[desired_keys[i]] = complete_data[desired_keys[i]]
```

(but to find something like `complete_data['items'][0]['another subitem']` which is much deeper(?) inside the dictionary)

**Some context**: APIs are sending more information than I need. The information comes packaged as a dict, which contains more sub-dicts and lists inside. I am trying to extract the information, as efficiently as possible, because I have to repeat this a million+ times. I am also looking to code as efficiently as possible because I have to modify this for more than one API.

Comment: but what if a certain key exists in more than one dicts?

Comment: Just as an FYI, you know you can do `my_dict['my_key']` instead of `my_dict.get('my_key')`, right? You use the `.get` method primarily if you want to get back some default value if your key is missing instead of throwing a KeyError exception. (This doesn't answer your main question, but perhaps it might help make your code a little more concise)

Comment: sounds like you need a recursive function but I can imagine this becoming ugly quickly.

Comment: I would need all instances of the key-value pairs, preferably in a list.

Comment: @Michael0x2a I know, sometimes data is missing. but yeah. Probably should have made the code a tad easier to read. Will Change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can store the keys in a list, and then write a function to do the item lookup for you:

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

def lookup(container, keys):
    return reduce(operator.getitem, keys, container)
```

With this, `complete_data['items'][0]['another subitem']` becomes

```
lookup(complete_data, ['items', 0, 'another subitem'])
```

Alternatively, here's a fail-safe implementation:

```
def lookup(container, keys, default=None):
    try:
        return reduce(operator.getitem, keys, container)
    except (IndexError, KeyError):
        return default
```

---

Then you can use this to easily collect all the data you need:

```
desired_keys=  {'name': ['name'],
                'another subitem': ['items', 0, 'another subitem']}

required_data= {}
for key, keys in desired_keys.items():
    required_data[key]= lookup(complete_data, keys)

print(required_data)
# output: {'name': 'bob', 'another subitem': 2}
```

Comment: what will lookup return if the key doesn't exist?

Comment: @Harrydewinton It'll throw a `KeyError` or `IndexError`. If that's a problem, just wrap the function body in a `try: ... except (KeyError, IndexError): return None`.

Comment: Would lookup be faster than foslock 's answer, where we define the function ourselves?

Comment: @Harrydewinton Almost certainly, because less of it is implemented in python. But I don't think the difference will be noticeable.

Comment: @Harrydewinton Rawing's answer may be marginally faster, but not enough in my opinion to sacrifice the explicitness of writing the logic of the method yourself. It's all personal preference, but I predict it's more likely that you'll have to explain the `reduce` implementation than the more familiar indexing to any other maintainers of this code.

Comment: @foslock Your are right, it took a little while for me wrap my head around Rawing's code, I have tried both of the options and settled on yours for readability, but its still good to learn some new stuff and Rawing's is a pretty neat solution

Answer (score 2):

### Simple Indexing Approach

This is something that many Python programmers have different opinions on, but what it boils down to is exactly how fault tolerant you want your code to be, if the input is malformed. If you are **positive** that the input follows that structure, you can simply use chained indexes:

```
try:
    sub_item_one = data['items'][0]['subitem']
except (KeyError, IndexError) as e:
    print("Unexpected structure, {}".format(e))
```

This access pattern will throw a `KeyError` or `IndexError` if the key/index is not present, so you can catch these exceptions and print/do what you wish to mitigate.

### Key Path Approach

There is a concept of a "key path" which is essentially a list like description of how to access a value nested within a dictionary/list structure. The above example would be a key path of `("items", 0, "subitem")`. I have used a *tuple* to represent it, but it could be any ordered sequence. We can write a simple method that takes a key path, and a structure, and safely extracts the value. We can also provide a `default` kwarg much like the `dict.get()` method so a default value can be returned in the event a `KeyError` or `IndexError` happens internally.

```
def get_key_path_value(key_path, obj, default=None):
    if not key_path:
        return obj
    try:
        for key in key_path:
            obj = obj[key]
    except (KeyError, IndexError):
        return default
    return obj

data = {
    "thing": [
        {"key": "value"},
        {"key2": "val2"}
    ],
}

print(get_key_path_value(("thing", 1, "key2"), data))
# val2
print(get_key_path_value(("thing", 0), data))
# {'key': 'value'}
print(get_key_path_value(("thing", 1, "key_none"), data))
# None
```

### Putting it all together

Since the actual question is about getting multiple keys at different levels of nesting within the structure, lets setup a mapping of **our local** key name to a key path we want to extract.

```
complete_data = {'name': 'bob',
                 'age': '22',
                 'items': [{'subitem': 1, 'another subitem': 2}, 123, 456]}

key_mapping = {
    "name": ("name",),
    "sub_item_one": ("items", 0, "subitem"),
}

pulled_data = {}
for key, key_path in key_mapping.iteritems():
    pulled_data[key] = get_key_path_value(key_path, complete_data)

print(pulled_data)
# {'sub_item_one': 1, 'name': 'bob'}
```

Comment: With a bit of care around types for the keys, the key_path could of course be _e.g._ `"thing/1/key2".split("/")`, which would aid putting the entire old-new mapping in a text file (csv) rather than script.

Comment: @GlennRogers Correct, but I hesitate to assume anything about the data returned from the API, and you very well can encode tuples/lists in JSON or another serialized format to be stored in CSVs or any external storage.